# What does "Qu'est-ce que c'est bon!" mean?

Tags: grammaire, sens, exclamations

This is [a title](http://www.pinterest.com/fillefrancaise/qu-est-ce-que-c-est-bon/).

I suppose this should say that something is good. But how can this make sense grammatically? Is not "Qu'est-ce que" always used for questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Qu'est-ce que* is here to say that the thing is very good, it is an exclamation here, and not a question.

"*Qu'est-ce qu'elle est belle*" means "She's really gorgeous". "*Belle*" is "pretty" in French, and  "*Qu'est-ce qu'…*"  helps accentuate her beauty.

Comment: Pourquoi cette réponse a-t-elle été votée contre ? Est-ce que elle est inexacte?

Comment: Je n'ai pas donné -1, mais je crois que c'est parce que la réponse ne souligne pas le fait que cette formulation n'est pas grammaticalement correcte pour une exclamation. On devrait dire "Qu'elle est belle !", par exemple.

Comment: Je ne peux pas voir que la réponse ait été moinssoyée mais je comprends la remarque de @Marc et je suis sur d'autres sites de SE où quand quelqu'un moinssoie il est invité à laisser un commentaire explicatif. Je comprends que quelqu'un qui vient à la recherche d'information puisse se poser la question.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Il me semble que vous confondez grammaticalement incorrect et d'un registre familier. « Qu'est-ce qu'elle est belle ! » est une exclamation interrogative couramment employée et grammaticalement correcte.

Comment: @Laure, pour voir si une réponse à été « moinssoyée », il suffit de cliquer sur son score.

Answer (score 5):

> Is not "Qu'est-ce que" always used for questions?

I think it is similar to the usage of *what* in *What a beauty!*

And you can think of the sentence you posted as meaning

> *What a goody!*

---

*Edit:*

As Laure pointed out:

The usage of "Qu'est-ce que" in this sentence is more akin to *how* than to *what*. So to clarify:

> Qu'est-ce qu'elle est belle!  --> How beautiful (she is)!

But in the case of your specific example:

> Qu'est-ce que c'est bon!  --> How good/delicious/tasty (it is)!

is common french but not so common english.

Comment: "What a + noun" emphasizes more on the noun and not enough on its qualities whereas *Qu'est-ce que c'est + adj* emphasizes on the adjective.  A "how+adj" construction would probably be more appropriate if you don't want to use an intensifying adverb.

Comment: I completely agree for the "how+adj" construction and it was the first to come to my mind when reading the question. I dismissed it because I thought "Qu'est-ce que" wouldn't translate to "how" but to "what".. but your comment just made me realize it completely can: Going to edit the answer!